# Apex Batch is not processing all records

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am running a batch to update opportunity records. I see that the query fetches around 1.1 million records but it processes only approx 100k records. I have checked the query in query editor and its working fine. Even when I process these records separately using the same code which batch is using to process its working as expected. Not sure why batch is not processing.

```
global class BatchAssignment implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{

    global Database.Querylocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id,Booking_Domain__c,Region__c,Primary_LOB__c,NA_Contract_Sales_Type__c,Owner_Sales_Group__c,Connected_Technologies_Opportunity__c FROM Opportunity where CreatedDate > LAST_N_YEARS:3 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC');
    }
   
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> oppList) {
        try{
            
            if(!oppList.isEmpty()){ 
                CustomBSNAReportingHandler.updateOpportunityBSNAReporting(oppList);
            } 
            if(test.isRunningTest()) { throw new DMLException();}
        }catch(Exception ex){
          
        }  
    }
   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // Peform post transaction update 
    }

}
```

Is there any restriction with batch? Why its behaving like this

Comment: Use clear language, not everybody knows that 1 lakh = 100,000

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the batch job still running? Check Setup -> Jobs to see if it finished.
2. You have empty try-catch that swallows any exceptions. Remove it and see what kind of errors you'll get.

Yes, it will mean that if there's 1 bad Opportunity - other 199 in same `execute()` call will fail to update. You can mitigate that by setting smaller chunk size (`Database.executeBatch(new BatchAssignment(), 10)`), clever use of `database.update(myrecords, false)` inside that method you're calling.

Maybe even look into https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm for some error raising (and handling it with some monitoring software? trigger that would convert them to Tasks related to problematic opportunities?)